# MULE DB query with variable table won't work

Tags: oracle, mule

I have a following situation: I have a name of the table in flow variable destTable and would like to put it into simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM #[destTable]
```

I am totally sure the table exists, the user who calls query has access to it, and that the name in my variable is correct and of type String - I am sure because if I put the name of table explicitly, it all works fine. The error I get is:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:457)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:400)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:926)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

The error says the name is invalid, but as I said - I've checked through loggers etc. that the name (T_ORG) contains no spaces nor any unprintable characters. I kindly please for swift response as to what am I missing or doing wrong, or maybe is it a problem with Mule software itself?

Additional Info 1: A query without "#[]" has a syntax colouring (brown and black, mostly); however, if I put #[] after the FROM clause, everything after it is coloured light-blue, as if it was a comment or in some other way ignored. Hope this helps to locate the problem.

Additional Info 2: Sample config to reproduce the error (assuming you have an Oracle XE etc.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd ">
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="cdf" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"/>
    <jdbc-ee:oracle-data-source name="cdf" user="CDF" password="CDF" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="Oracle Data Source"/>

    <flow name="sampleFlow" doc:name="sampleFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="myVar" value="T_ORG" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="selectAll" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database">
            <jdbc-ee:query key="selectAll" value="SELECT * FROM #[myVar]"/>
        </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but the examples seem to use the `#[]` form in a way that looks analogous to bind variables, so I'm wondering if under the hood the `value` is converted to a JDBC query with bind variables and the equivalent values are added as parameters; so the query is `SELECT * from ?`. You can't bind object names, and if it treated `?` as literally the table name when parsing the statement, that might explain the error message?

Comment: Thank you for the response - yes, that's what I think might happened, and that bothers me. I'm still trying to find some kind of workaround for this, but so far nothing works for me. :(

Comment: If that's right then you probably have to start with what JDBC can do, and then convert that to mule. I don't know of any way to make the table name variable in JDBC though, so I don't think you can do what you want. The closest I can think off is to have a procedure in the DB that you pass the table name to and it returns a `sys_refcursor` of the appropriate data. Or a view with a base-table column to filter on. Unless the table structures are identical, though, I'm not sure making it generic is going to be all that helpful in the end - you still have to handle the data when it comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long pause, I returned to this subject by accident and... Actually, you CAN make the whole query dynamic(as of Mule 3.3.2, at least); I found the clue here: [Very dynamic JDBC query in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870038/very-dynamic-jdbc-query-in-mule)

and here a sample project( you need locally running ActiveMQ server, and local Oracle DB; or edit the code just to make it work):

http://pastebin.com/PcPz2LZy

hope that it helps someone as it did help me! :)

Comment: That solution creates an endpoint in memory for each different SQL that you are using with "jdbc://...". That means you're increasing the memory usage with each different SQL and that's why it's not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 3):

Only parameters of the query can be dynamic (i.e. Mule expressions). Tables cannot be dynamic in the query.

Comment: Thank you for the response, though it saddens me :( I've also tried to parse the entire query into variable, then put it in query, but it didn't work either. Do you know of any way to make it work? In production DB I'm going to deal with some tables(at least 5) and would like to keep the entire process as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the name as a property in app.properties file and then using it? 
Something like this `<jdbc-ee:query key="selectAll" value="SELECT * FROM ${tableName}"/>` where "tableName" is a defined value in the app.properties file.